# A page with 3 fixed-width cols

Tags: html, css

I wanna create a page with 3 fixed-width cols by using

For example, the page has a default width 1024px, consist of header,div1,div2,div3, each of them has a fixed width. The layout pls see the left side of image when Chrome is maximize.

When user restore Chrome to 600px width size or something. Becuase all the element has fixed width, so  shall be hidden and  shall be half show. And there is one scroll bar at bottom.

[image]

Here is some of my code, could you point out or show me some sample how I could do this?

HTML

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2c3e50;
    background-color: #e8eaf4;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.header{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 25;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #daddf7;
}

.div1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px solid #daddf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(44,75,248,0.2);
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(44,75,248,0.2);
}

.div2 {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div3{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">   
    <title>三栏-固定宽度布局</title>    
</head>   
<body>   
    <div id="app">   
        <div class="header" style="width: 1024px; height: 60px;"></div>
        <div class="div1" style="width: 200px; height: 328px; top: 60px;"></div>
        <div class="div2" style="width: 700px; height: 328px; left: 180px; top: 60px;"></div>
        <div class="div3" style="width: 124px; height: 328px; top: 60px;"></div>
    </div>   
</body>   
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your problem, Is this what you want ? https://jsbin.com/duvepariha/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap child `divs` using `wapper` and set main width `1024px` then set child widths accordingly and to create grid of boxes use `display: inline-block`,

```css
.wapper{
  width: 1024px;
}

.div1,.div2,.div3{
   background: #ccc;
   display: inline-block;
   height: 328px;
}

.div1 {
   width: 246px; 
} 

.div2 {
   width: 524px; 
}

.div3 {
   width: 246px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wapper">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this may help you.

Please try below css

```css
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
}
.div1,.div2,.div3{
     display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
     border-top: 2px solid #daddf7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(44,75,248,0.2);
    box-shadow: 2px 0px 4px 0px rgba(44,75,248,0.2);
    background-color:#eee;
}
.div1{
  width:20%;
  height: 328px;
}
.div2{
 width:65%;
 height: 328px; 
}
.div3{
 width:12%;
 height: 328px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="div1"></div>
        <div class="div2" ></div>
        <div class="div3"></div>
        <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Bootstrap**

col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 means that the screen will be divided into 4|4|4 equal portions on all device sizes.

```css
.equal {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row equal" style="height: 100vh;">
    <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color: #e9d66b"></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color: #ff9966"></div>
    <div class="col-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" style="background-color: #89cff0"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nj6ga0w8/)